# Is there alternative way to change index inside the for loop?

Tags: for-loop

Assumed question I don’t wanna 7 in the random number so I do this. I know this is not a good example. Sorry for that first.

```
int temp[8];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ ){
    temp[i] = random(8);
    if (temp[i] == 7){
        temp[i] = random(8);
        i--;
    }
}
```

My ideal is don’t do i— where inside the for loop. Use extra space to record it then do the somehhing outside the first for loop. The code will become:

```
ArrayList i_index;
int count = 0 ;
int temp[8];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ ){
    temp[i] = random(8);
    if (temp[i] == 7){
        i_index.add(i) ;    
    }
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ ){
    if ( i_index.get(count) == i ){
        temp[i] ++ ; //do something or whatever just not return 7 
        count ++ ;  
    }
}
```

Is that correct or is there any better ideal?
Or hope someone can give a good example.

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: i think is javascript not?

Comment: It's not JavaScript. Looks like C or pseudo-code maybe.

Comment: Yes just pseudo-code.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this without knowing more about what `xxx` and `YYY` do, and whether the first version gives the correct result. If the result of `xxx` does not depend on the action of `YYY`, then the first version will hang when it encounters `xxx==true`. But if the first version cannot hang, then the result of `xxx` *must* depend on the action of `YYY`, at least sometimes, but if the... There are too many branches.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I think you need to restate your question.  What are you trying to accomplish?  I see YYY inside a for loop, what do you mean by do the YYY outside the for loop?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in manipulating the index like that. I do it my self very often.

For example lately I had to find items in an array that might come in pairs but not always so the loop looked similar to this (it's pseudocode):

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    item1 = items[i]
    if (i + 1 < itemCount)
    {
       item2 = items[i+1]
       if (item2 is a pair to item1)
       {
           ...do something
           i++ // item2 is already processed so skip it next time by increasing the i
       }
    }
}
```

If your algorithm requires it I would say it's totaly ok to manipulate the `i`. Sometimes there is no other way (like in my example).

---

EDIT: Now that you showed us the full case I still think it is ok in to change the `i` in your algorithm. However there are a few other solutions possible:

**Example-1**: you could use a `while-loop` inside the `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ )
{
    int num = random(8);
    while(num == 7)
    {
        num = random(8);
    }
    temp[i] = num;
}
```

**Example-2**: or the other way round by using a `do-while` inside the `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ )
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        num = random(8);
    } 
    while (num == 7);

    temp[i] = num;
}
```

**Example-3**: or just a single `do-while` loop until it finds 8 numbers different from 7:

```
int count = 0;
int num;

do
{
    num = random(8);
    if (num != 7)
    {
        temp[count] = num;
        count++;
    }
}
// Repeat as long as there are fewer then 8 items or the number is 7
while (count < 8 || num == 7);
```

**Example-4**: if you can use a collection other then an array, like a list or something where you can add items it can even be simpler:

```
int num;
bool isValidNumber;
do
{
    num = random(8);
    isValidNumber = (num != 7);
    if (isValidNumber)
    {
        numList.add(num);
    }
}
// Repeat as long as there are fewer then 8 items or the number is invalid
while (numList.count < 8 || !isValidNumber);
```

Comment: See the EDIT. I think this migtht be a _better_ solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes your answer is right but use two loops. Is there any way just use one loop? Maybe this example is not good sorry i just want to make sure manipulate index inside the loop is correct?

Comment: Although wait... see example-3.

Comment: It's seem use another loop batter then control index inside the loop. Or just sacrifice extra spaces.

Comment: If you can take a collection and not an array it might even look like the example-4 that I've just added ;-]

Comment: By the way I really remember if control index inside the loop like this kind example. It will easy cause some unpredicted bugs. If not really need to do that. Use alternative way is better.

Comment: If you have a bug in the condition checking the numbers or the random function gives you only the 7 :-P any of the loops will run indefinitely unless you implement a time out or a max repetition counter.

Answer (score 0):

Yea what I typically do is use a second index or counter variable like you've shown in your code.

```
count=0;
for(i=0,i<800,i++)
{
    if(x)
    {
       //do something using count
       //ex: array[count] = i+3*count;
       count++;
    }
}
```

I don't think your second loop is probably necessary, but it also isn't entirely clear what you are looking to do. Regardless, that's how you use a secondary counter inside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to try in this way since not sure what language you going to use and what mean by XXX and YYY action.

Example in PHP

```
$arr=array();

    for($x=0;$x<8;$x++)
    {
        if(xxx)
        {
            array_push($arr,$x);
        }
    }
```

Now we have a array which matched with XXX condition, so we just do YYY action based on what it stored in array.

```
foreach($arr as $y)
{
    YYY($y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to run the loop again with the same `i` (without decrementing it in the loop body). One option is to move the increment into the loop body and use a `continue` like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ) { // <-- remove the i++ from here
    if (xxx){
        YYY; // do something
        // i--; // <-- don't need to subtract one from i
        continue; // <-- will rerun the loop with the same i
    }
    i++; // <-- add it here.
}
```

Another option would be an `else` like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ) { // <-- remove the i++ from here
    if (xxx){
        YYY; // do something
        // i--; // <-- don't need to subtract one from i
    } else {
        i++; // <-- add it here.
    }
}
```

And then you don't need the `continue;`

Based on your newly updated post,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ ){
    temp[i] = random(7); // <-- 0,6 (will never be 7).
}
```

If you want a gap, I suggest you still reduce the range and test like,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ ){
    int r = random(8); // <-- assuming it's 8 exclusive,
    temp[i] =  (r != 7) ? r : 8; // <-- skip 7.
}
```

Comment: ...but it will never be 8 too. You don't know how the particular random function works. Maybe it generates numbers inclusive the 8? ;-) the OP didn't specify the language or the implementation of `random` and maybe he wants the 8 but not the 7 or any other number that he wants to exclude.

Comment: @t3chb0t Added a cleaner way to *skip 7*. Obviously, seven above might be generalized to `n`.